# What versions/flavors of WinZip can be opened by the gnu.java.util.zip.dll v.6.0.140.8?

Tags: java, zip, classpath

Evaluating a third party data processing tool, I have bumped into a case where some WinZip files cause an exception:

```
Caused by: gnu.java.util.zip.ZipException: Unknown compression method 98
    at gnu.java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:470)
```

I have seen this with files created with WinZip 11.2 and newer.  What's the latest version of WinZip (or compatible compression method) that the zip.dll can handle?

I've been hunting for some reference on this, but other than unversioned source code, I have had little luck so far.

Comment: Less interested in WinZip's formats than I am in an understanding of what this java zip library can support.  Thanks though.

Comment: I also wonder, what is the library, that includes `gnu.java.util.zip.ZipFile`? Can you give a project name? Searching this classname in google returns the link only to this very page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Winzip website has a page on [additional compression algorithms](http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm) which mentions compression algorithm 98. It claims this first appeared in Winzip version 10.0 beta.

I believe all versions of Winzip are capable of producing zip files which are readable by older utilities; it's just a question of which options you select.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinZip#History , I'd say it can probably open anything that winzip 8 could open, and later inventions except for unicode support are unique to winzip and will break in other programs if used. I haven't looked into it though.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably comes from the Classpath project http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/